# How to send product price alert in magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.4

I am using magento 1.4 . Any one please tell me how to send product price alert.
Do i need to change any code for that. If i need to change the code, possible to tell me where exactly to change and what to change?

Answer (score 1):

Price alerts are sent by `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::process()` which is called regularly by cron. Any changes you want to make to how alerts are sent will be in there.

If you want to create an alert that will be sent later see `Mage_ProductAlert_AddController::priceAction()`. It simply creates a `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Price` object and saves it with a customer.